# How can I check the iOS version in compilation time?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I’m building a class that has some functionalities only supported for iOS 11.0 and above. When I try to build the project with target iOS 10.3, I get a syntax error; however, I don’t want to change the project configuration just yet.

I tried using the `#if` directive, but apparently I’m not allowed to use `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` as a condition for compilation. I would like to know if there’s a way to identify the iOS version in compilation time. Runtime solutions don’t work because the error will stop the project from being properly built.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  `@available` is the correct directive for conditional compilation. Are you actually having an issue with Swift 5 syntax?

Comment: Hi @Paulw11. I'm deallocating memory using `vm_address_t(bitPattern: _Pointer?)`. When I build, it works fine. When I try to archive the project using target 11.0 it works fine. However, if the target is 10.3, I get the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'thread_act_array_t' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>') to expected argument type 'Int32'`. According to my research, this has to do with 32-bit architecture supported by iOS 10.3. That's why I want Xcode to only compile this function for iOS 11 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create multiple Targets, each with their own Deployment Target. Set one target to have iOS10 and one to have iOS11. Then, only build against the deployment type you are currently interested in.